# Concatenating/superimposing two samples matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to concatenate 2 samples with *preference* for Sample_2:

```
eg. Sample_1= rand(1000,28), Sample_2=normrnd(1.91,0.266,1000,28)
```

[image]

OK so now I want to superimpose `Sample_2` ontop of `Sample_1`, but with preference  for the points of sample_2 (eg 80% sample 2 and 20% sample1). Ie i'd like more of Sample_2 points and less of Sample_1. This is for uncertainty analysis for a monte-carlo sampling for a model.

Perhaps something like:

```
Total_sample=randsample([Sample_1 Sample_2],1000,28,'false',[0.8 0.2]);
```

> Error using randsample (line 74) POPULATION must be a vector.

and

> Error using randsample (line 90) W must have length 56.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward approach would be to generate random indices, and use them to overwrite 80% of the samples in `Sample_1` with samples from `Sample_2`:

```
%// Copy samples from Sample_1
Total_Sample = Sample_1;

%// Overwrite 80% of the samples with values from Sample_2
N = numel(Sample_1);
idx = randperm(N);
Total_Sample(idx(1:0.8 * N)) = Sample_2(idx(1:0.8 * N));
```

Alternatively, the second part can also be implemented like so:

```
N = numel(Sample_1);
idx = randsample(1:N, 0.8 * N);
Total_Sample(idx) = Sample_2(idx);
```